# Methods are giving meaningless names for their variables android studio 4.2

Tags: android, listener, android-studio, actionlistener, ratingbar

I'm developing in android studio for quite some time, but a curtain problem started striking me when downloaded on my new pc.
When setting a listener for a widget(ex. RatingBar), the given methods name their variables in a meaningless way like "float v" or "boolean b".

```
RatingBar bar = (RatingBar) findViewById(R.id.rating);
bar.setOnRatingBarChangeListener(new RatingBar.OnRatingBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void (RatingBar ratingBar, float v, boolean b) {
            ...
        }
    });
```

Instead of:

```
RatingBar bar = (RatingBar) findViewById(R.id.rating);
bar.setOnRatingBarChangeListener(new RatingBar.OnRatingBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void RatingBar ratingBar, float rating, boolean fromUser) {
            ...
        }
    });
```

As anyone have an Input to help me fix this?
Thanks!

Comment: It's just a bug in Android Studio. I use Eclipse & ADT and see similar things such as naming parameters as arg0, arg1 etc etc. If you want sensible names you'll need to go to the Android reference to check what they should be and rename them yourself.

Comment: Thank's for the quick answer @Squonk. the thing is, i started getting this kind of thing **just now**(didn't have this on my last pc). I know what each var means, i'm just looking for a way to prefix this. Tried to Re-install, didn't help. Any thought?

Answer (score 0):

It's very old post but maybe it will be useful for who looking for this;

With using the SDK Manager, you need to download the sources of the sdk version that you are targeting in build.gradle file.